# Best way to display pdf embedded in browser (chrome, IE11/Edge, Safari)

Tags: angularjs, pdf, cross-browser, mobile-safari, microsoft-edge

I am trying to display a pdf which is created by the GET call of a RESTful service. In the HTML I am using a object tag as below

```
<object data={{$ctrl.miEstimatePdfData}} type="application/pdf" 
    width="100%" height="100%" alt="pdf" class="view-pdf_document"> 
    <p>Estimate Preview Cannot be displayed.</p>    
</object>
```

In the js file

```
miEstimateService.getMitchellEstimate(response.estimate.id)
    .then(function (response) {
    var blob = new Blob([(response.data)], { type: 'application/pdf' });
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        $window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, "estimatePreview.pdf");
    } else {
        var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        $scope.miEstimatePdfData = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(fileUrl);
    }
});
```

This works flawlessly in chrome
Since IE11/ Edge does not allow displaying of the blob URL, I am using the .msSaveOrOpenBlob, but this does not open the pdf inside the browser window. It promts the user to save or open the pdf and opens it in Acrobat Reader (IE11) or in a new browser window (Edge). 
In Safari, the PDF is rendered correctly in the browser but is not free flowing or scrollable, so most of the second page is not visible.

I have researched a lot and looked at a lot of the SO questions. Is there some solution which works for all the browsers - chrome, IE11/Edge and Safari?

Thanks,
SDD

Comment: Check out [PDFObject](https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject), it's a good utility for embedding PDF's and states that it supports IE11. If you want to download PDF's then [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) is a good library for saving.